# undefined symbols (shared library as a part of another shared library, build via cmake)

Tags: linker, cmake, shared-libraries

I'm compiling my shared library, which is meant to be used in another (main) shared library of mine.
So, the whole set-up is compiled using cmake roughly as follows:

For the "main" shared library:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(lib_outer SHARED
   ....
   )

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(lib_outer 
    lib_inner 
    ...
    )
```

For the additional shared library:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(lib_inner SHARED 
  .... 
   )
```

Now, the `lib_inner` uses some functions defined and implemented in the second `lib_outer`, Which leads to `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` linking error.

Can i somehow tell the `cmake` to ignore those? 
I shall i use something like 'external`when using those functions inside`lib_inner` ?
I guess the solution is simple, but i never came across such a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion with colleagues, it seems that the only good option is to compile the two libraries simultaneously as a whole. Effectively combining the CMakeLists.txt files which before were used to produce two separate, but dependent libraries.

Comment: I think you and your colleagues came up with the correct solution.  Circular references between libraries are painful at best — to be avoided whenever possible.  And creating one library instead of two is one simple way of dealing with the issue.  It also simplifies the distribution of the product, and the linking of the programs that use the libraries (now 'library').